# AttributeError: Button instance has no attribute 'set'

Tags: python, tkinter

i want to print the path of the uploaded file, so i used .set(). Tried to use global variable but it doesn't overwrite the file name when i change the file

```
def callback():
    file_name.set(askopenfilename(filetypes=(("Music File", "*.mp3"),("Video files", "*.mpg"))))


file_name = Button(root, text="open", command=callback)
file_name.pack(side=Tkinter.TOP)
```

i got this error,any advice for that?

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\Python27\lib\lib-tk\Tkinter.py", line 1486, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "C:\Users\Xavier_\Desktop\PROJECT_FINAL(please don't edit)\segmentation_GUI.py", line 20, in callback
    file_name.set(askopenfilename(filetypes=(("Music File", "*.mp3"),("Video files", "*.mpg"))))
AttributeError: Button instance has no attribute 'set'
```

Comment: What are you trying to do when you call `set`?  Do you want the text of the button to change to the chosen filename?  As written, the answer to your question is, "`Button`s have no set method"

Comment: You say you want to "print the path of the uploaded file".  Are you looking for the `print` function?  What do you mean by "print"?

Comment: Maybe you're looking for a [`StringVar`](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/variable.htm)? That has a `set` method, and it can be attached to some kinds of widgets, so that setting it updates the widget's text. Or maybe not, it's hard to tell, but it's a guess…

Comment: First rule of debugging: assume the error message is telling you the truth. The error message says that a button instance doesn't have the method "set". That is true. The question is now, why do you think it should have a set method, and what do you think that method does?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you want to replace the text in the button with the name of the selected file.

As the error message suggests, the button has no `set` method. You *could* use `configure`...

```
def callback():
    file_name.configure(text=askopenfilename(...))
```

But you should rather use a [`Variable`](http://infohost.nmt.edu/tcc/help/pubs/tkinter/web/control-variables.html) instead. Create a `StringVar` and bind it to the `Button`, then use `set` to update and `get` to retrieve the value of that variable, i.e. the text on the button.

```
def callback():
    var.set(askopenfilename(filetypes=(("Music File", "*.mp3"),("Video files", "*.mpg"))))

root = Tk()
var = StringVar()
var.set("select file...")
file_name = Button(root, textvariable=var, command=callback)
file_name.pack(side=TOP)
root.mainloop()
```